# tomcat webapps filenotfound exception for resource file getresource

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, jax-ws

I have an webservice application that takes preview screen-shot of social networking websites using PhantomJS. When there is an error, the catch block calls a function to fetch the error image png file instead of the screen-shot. However, it returns no response. The tomcat logs show error as FileNotFound exception. The image file is being fetched as a resource. The file is present 
in the same folder as classes under webapps.

java.io.FileNotFoundException: File 'C:\Data\Tomcat%207.0\webapps\FederatedSearch\WEB-INF\classes\com\ez\rest\EmptyPage.png' does not exist

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("EmptyPage.png");
```

Tomcat version: 7.0.47

JRE: 1.7 update 45

Could anyone please help on this?

Comment: Try to load resource using getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("EmptyPage.png") method

Comment: What is the package of the class that is containing this code ?

Comment: It is a webservice deployed as a war file in Tomcat 7.0.47. However, I found the cause of the issue which was the space in the name of the Tomcat folder which is "Tomcat 7.0". It should be without space. It is hard to realize though with the "%20" introduced in the logs.